# How do you count the total number of objects in query set, and display the total number in a CreateView generic view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need to know how to print the total number of objects in a query set for my CreateView generic view.
I don't know how to connect a variable or something so I can process the information onto my template.

CreateView class in views.py:

```
 class CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['author', 'title', 'category', 'article']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'blog/create.html'
```

Here is my template: templates/blog/create.html

```
  {% extends 'blog/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% include 'blog/navbar.html' %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-body">
        
        <form method="POST">
            <a style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'home' %}">&#8592; Go back</a>
            <br />
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>{{ form.author.label }}:</label>
            <br />
            {{ form.author}}
            <br />

            <label>{{ form.title.label }}:</label>
            <br />
            {{ form.title }}
            <br />
            <label>{{ form.category.label }}:</label>
            <br />
            {{ form.category }}
            <br />
            <label>{{ form.article.label }}:</label>
            <br />
            {{ form.article }}
            <br />
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Current number of blogs</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ ** I want total number of objects in here** }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Is there anything you can do to help?

I'm trying to say you currently have "total number of objects in query set" blogs.

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Am I forgetting a variable I have to pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the number of records to the context, so:

```
class CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['author', 'title', 'category', 'article']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'blog/create.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['nobjects'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return context
```

and render this in the template with:

```
{{ nobjects }}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much , I was thinking how to do it for so long! Keep shining!

Comment: I got it to work, but could you explain it if possible?